# Understanding Policy Iteration and Value Iteration

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-iteration, value-iteration

I have read an answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370015/what-is-the-difference-between-value-iteration-and-policy-iteration) but still cannot capture the ideas behind it.

In [Sutton's book, section Value Iteration](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node44.html), it is said that

> In fact, the policy evaluation step of policy iteration can be truncated in several ways without losing the convergence guarantees of policy iteration. One important special case is when policy evaluation is stopped after just one sweep (one backup of each state). This algorithm is called value iteration.

When I look at the algorithm (in the same link above), since we loop until the error threshold $\Delta < \theta$, we must "sweep" through the state space multiple times. Could someone explain the idea that "policy evaluation is stopped after just one sweep" above?

Also, in the section [Generalized Policy Iteration](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node46.html),

> In value iteration, for example, only a single iteration of policy evaluation is performed in between each policy improvement.

In the value iteration algorithm: we compute all possible $q(s,a)$ <- policy evaluation, then assign the maximum $q(s,a)$ to $V(s)$ based on action $a$ <- policy improvement, then store the error $\Delta$. In general, we have sequence:

- compute all $q(s,a)$: policy evaluation
- choose $a$ that maximizes $q(s,a)$ and assign it to $V(s)$: policy improvement
- update error term $\Delta$
- compute all $q(s',a)$: policy evaluation
- choose $a$ that maximizes $q(s',a)$ and assign it to $V(s')$: policy improvement
- update error term $\Delta$
- ...

Then between each policy improvement, we have one iteration of policy evaluation. Is this the correct way to understand the above claim from the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though as you stated in the value iteration algo we loop until the error threshold $\Delta < \theta$ we must sweep through the state space multiple times, the single sweep (one backup of each state) mentioned in your reference simply means that one line in the referenced algo which is $v \leftarrow V(s)$. Thus in value iteration the updated value at every iteration step of any state is *not* that state's value function, but some intermediate value of an iterative process which theoretically converges to that state's value function eventually.

On the other hand, in each evaluation step of the policy iteration algo we do multiple sweeps to arrive at each state's value function via another iterative process *within* one policy evaluation and improvement cycle, which obviously involves more computation steps than value iteration. So in practice you could use value iteration or truncated policy iteration to stop earlier before arriving at each state's true value function in a theoretically potentially infinite iterative process.

Finally you could separate value update for your sequence of each state from policy improvement in your referenced algo's while-until loop since it's implemented in an elementwise fashion, and yes between each policy improvement we have one iteration (sweep) of policy evaluation for each state.